# SQL query in linq pseudocode

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, pseudocode

I need to output only the last record from the table, but only those users who are in the group. I can only display those who are in the group. But I can't get the last record.
I wrote 2 requests, the first one gives an error, the second one outputs all the records...

```
foreach (var item1 in brigades.Persons)
            {
                var persontrack =
                from s in new DataContext().GetTable<PersonTrack>()
                join t in a on s.PersonId equals t.Id
                where t.Id == item1.Id
                group s by s.Id into grp
                from last in (from custRec in grp where custRec.Id == grp.Max(cr => cr.Id) select custRec)
                select last;
                ps.AddRange(persontrack);
            }

foreach (var item in brigades.Persons)
        {
            var persontrack = from s in new DataContext().GetTable<PersonTrack>()
                              join t in brigades.Persons on s.PersonId equals t.Id
                              where t.Id == item.Id
                              orderby s.Id
                              descending
                              select s;
            ps.AddRange(persontrack);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is only possible with the C# way of writing linq.

### Quick fix

Your 2nd query will make it if you add [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) (the query gets *translated* to sql, even written this way, and only last element is returned).

```
using (var db = new DataContext())    // create once to gain performance
{
    foreach (var item in brigades.Persons)
    {
        var persontrack = (from s in db.GetTable<PersonTrack>()
                           join t in brigades.Persons on s.PersonId equals t.Id
                           where t.Id == item.Id
                           orderby s.Id
                           descending
                           select s).FirstOrDefault();
        if (persontrack != null)
            ps.Add(persontrack);
    }
}   // DataContext is disposed here
```

or this would also work, but would be odd to add nulls:

```
ps.Add(persontrack.FirstOrDefault());
```

---

### Alternative

However, using **foreach causes several calls to the db**. You could rewrite it into a single query like this:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var eachLastTrack = from s in db.GetTable<PersonTrack>()
                        join t in brigades.Persons on s.PersonId equals t.Id
                        // group by PersonId instead, to avoid foreach!
                        group s by s.PersonId into grp 
                        select grp.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                        // note: FirstOrDefault() applied for each "t.Id"!
    ps.AddRange(eachLastTrack);
}
```